# Hamburger menu in sencha extjs

Tags: extjs

[image]**Hamburger** menu in **extjs**?  Needed some examples of that.
i have tried extjs examples but couldn't find any examples someone could help me on that.

Comment: How would you like that menu to behave ? Can you post an example from other apps? I don't think there is one out of the box. But it's easy to make one with just 2 components put together.

Comment: Thanks for the response @pagep, I have edited my post kindly check

Comment: So something similar to this menu on the left? http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/examples/admin-dashboard/#dashboard

I think those can be done with tree list and than you would just add opening on the button http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#tree-list

Comment: Treelist is fine when i click the menu icon how will that navigation drawer is open from the left side.

Comment: For an example refer this image https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-ab&biw=1366&bih=654&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=fSsFXITVN5nfrQGIg7Uo&q=hamburger+navigation+menu+extjs+gif&oq=hamburger+navigation+menu+extjs+gif&gs_l=img.3...1968.3133..3650...0.0..0.379.986.1j1j0j2......1....1..gws-wiz-img.fblA69Pra3c#imgrc=ERtP3Pj06S1OHM: